# Lots of httpd processes

Tags: apache, centos, httpd.conf

My apache server on CentOS7 spawns a lot of processes that consumes server resources, and the log shows a lots of:

`"OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16 (internal dummy connection)"`

There was a suggestion, that this is because of IPv6 enabled, but IPv6 is disabled so I am kinda stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is part of the child process management. Depending on your load, you could try adjusting the parameters (`ServerLimit`, `MaxSpareServers`). Or if possible try some other MPM like event. Im assuming you are using prefork.

Answer (score 0):

Prefork MPM always runs few minimum defined processes as spare, see the config variable MinSpareServers, so new requests do not need to wait for new process to start.

Check the config file: **/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf**